# Print Laravel JSON Response

Tags: laravel-5

How can I echo this json data separately on two different places on blade file.

[{"client_id":"D118","total":46}]

Client_id & total without foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make helper function something like:

```
function getClientId($json){
    $array = json_decode($json,true);
    if(isset($array[0]['client_id'])){
        return $array[0]['client_id'];
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

function getTotal($json){
    $array = json_decode($json,true);
    if(isset($array[0]['total'])){
        return $array[0]['total'];
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

best precise to make helper function to create Helper.php file and make it auto loaded or for testing purpose you can go with web.php file just paste this function there and call it from any blade file.

Good luck...

Comment: getting this error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: if your data is in json format then it will work I checked in my local system in your blade file you have to call function like this {!! getClientId($json_data) !!}